# Is it possible to constrain a type by the name of a method?

Tags: c#, generics

For example, types `AA`, `BB`, and `CC` all have a method `Close()`. They do not implement any kind of interface with `void Close()` in it. Is it possible to do a type constraint based on the type having a method called `Close`?

```
public static void CloseThis<T>(this T openObject) where T : Closeable
{
    openObject.Close();
}
```

Comment: ...only if they implement an interface. Is there something stopping you from doing that?

Comment: They are types I cannot edit.

Comment: wrap class, implement closeable, or extend if you can

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Abc
{
    public void Close()
    { }
}

interface IClosable
{
    void Close();
}

class AbcClosable : Abc, IClosable
{ }

class GenClosable<T> where T : IClosable
{ }
```

then use

```
var genClosable = new GenClosable<AbcClosable>();
```

or create generic extension method

```
public static void CloseThis<T>(this T openObject) where T : Closeable
{
    openObject.Close();
}
```

then use it as

```
var abcClosable = new AbcClosable();
abcClosable.CloseThis();
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me, a solution should be based on aggregation not on inheritance. Why? "They are types I cannot edit". I think because this type belongs to another developer|company|etc and inheritance increases coupling, so the solution should be based on aggregation.

Please note, any of `AA`, `BB` or `CC` can be `sealed` or could be `sealed`

```
public sealed class Aa
{
    public void Close()
    {
    }
}

public interface IClosable
{
    void Close();
}

internal class AbcClosable : IClosable
{
    private readonly Aa _aa;

    public AbcClosable(Aa aa)
    {
        _aa = aa;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _aa.Close();
    }
}

public static class CloseableExtensions
{
    public static void CloseThis<T>(this T value)
        where T : IClosable
    {
        value.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to test if an object has a close method and then call it if it exists.

```
    static void CloseIfClosable(object o)
    {
        Type oType = o.GetType();
        MethodInfo closeMethod = oType.GetMethod("Close");
        if (closeMethod != null)
        {
            closeMethod.Invoke(o, new object[] { });
        }
    }
```

Generally speaking you want to avoid reflection but if you are being forced to use troublesome types outside your control it might be the best option.